# The Fixed Point Theorem in Artin's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetry

Theorem 7.3.2 Let G be a p-group, and let S be a finite set on which G operates. If the order of S is not divisible by p, there is a fixed point for the operation of G on S - an element s whose stabilizer is the whole group.

Do not how to prove it..

Comment: $S$ is the disjoint union of the distinct orbits under the action of $G$. What is the cardinality of an orbit $G\cdot s$?

Comment: The key here is the class equation.

Comment: Hi, @DanielFischer, do you mean that S's conjugacy classes' order can only be p's power?

Comment: $S$ is just a set, so "conjugacy classes" is the wrong term. The orbits under the action of $G$ are the interesting thing (when $G$ acts on itself by conjugation, then the orbits are the conjugacy classes). But yes, every orbit's cardinality is a power of $p$ - why?

Comment: Yes, @DanielFischer, I could understand the orbit of each G*s has order power of p as the cardinality of G's conjugacy classes are power of p. But why there is a fixed point in the set S?

Comment: If there were no fixed point, what would that imply about the cardinality of $S$?

Comment: Finally, I understand it, the G*s is a orbit whose order is power of p, and as G*S = S, the S is constructed by some orbits whose orders are all power of p. Then there must be some '1' in S. Thank you, @DanielFischer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume there is no fixed point. Since |G|=|stab(s)||orbit(s)| and |G|=p^a then the |orbit(s)|=p^m where m is not 0. But |S| is the sum of the orbits. Each orbit is divisible by p, which makes |S| divisible by p. Contradiction.